# Negative Free Memory

Tags: java, sorting, memory

Sometimes, this code prints a negative number, like -64.
The value is in KB.

What could be happenning?

```
long memoriaInicial = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024;
sort(vector);
System.Out.Println(memoriaInicial - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1024);
```

Comment: do you think the "long" type would be a problem?

Comment: What's wrong with that? Perhaps you could explain why you expect a positive result.

Comment: Thats a normal math hehe. Imagine my program starts with 50mb free memory. Then I use 10mb. So 50 - 40 = 10mb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means after you've sorted, the garbage collector has probably freed more memory and you have more than you started out with.

Comment: hmmm..this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927396/how-can-i-disable-java-garbage-collector says that the garbage collector only run when there is not space, but my command is: Xms850M -Xmx850M. And I am pretty sure the method didnt used 850mb

Comment: Well, I don't know much about Java, but it's quite similar to .NET in a lot of ways and in .NET, the garbage collector can be run at arbitrary times. I think I do know enough about Java to assume your strange result is the result of garbage collection, though.

Comment: I read again all my code, and I think I'm really using a lot memory. That's problably the correct answer. Thanks minitech.