# Do we have to free an allocated ByteBuffer manually?

Tags: java, lwjgl, nio

I'm writing some stuff that uses `ByteBuffer`s. In the [docs of the API](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/BufferUtils.html) it says

> There is no way to free a buffer explicitly (without JVM specific
>   reflection). **Buffer objects are subject to GC** and it usually takes two
>   GC cycles to free the off-heap memory after the buffer object becomes
>   unreachable.

However in a [SO post's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091615/difference-between-on-heap-and-off-heap) I read

> BigMemory uses the memory address space of the JVM process, via direct
>   ByteBuffers that **are not subject to GC** unlike other native Java
>   objects.

Now what should I do, shall I free the created buffer? Or do I misunderstand something in the docs or the answer?

Comment: Will do. Papa Google popped up the docs first then some SO posts which caused the misunderstanding, hence the question. 
It is good to have that link here for me and for anyone else who might stumble upon this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how you create the buffer, there are many possible use cases. Regular `ByteBuffer.allocate()` will be created on the heap and will be collected by the GC. Other options e.g. native memory might not.

Terracotta BigMemory is a type of native off-heap memory which is not governed by the JVM GC. If you allocate a buffer in this type of memory you have to clear it yourself.

It might be a good idea to clear the buffer even if it's allocated in the heap memory. GC will take care of collecting unused buffer it but this will take some time.

Comment: Thanks, but the reason for confusion was the part _via direct ByteBuffers that are not subject to GC_. So the Terracotta BM uses `ByteBuffer`s differently? Or are their same names just a coincidence?

Answer (score 3):

As the documentation of the `BufferUtils` in LWJGL also say: There is no way to explicitly *free* a `ByteBuffer`.

The `ByteBuffer` objects that are allocated with the standard mechanism (namely, by directly or indirectly calling `ByteBuffer#allocateDirect`) are subject to GC, and will be cleaned up eventually.

The answer that you linked to seems to refer to the *BigMemory* library in particular. Using JNI, you **can** create a (direct) `ByteBffer` that is *not* handled by the GC, and where it is up to you to actually free the underlying data.

---

However, a short advice: When dealing with LWJGL and other libraries that rely on (direct) `ByteBuffer` objects for the data transfer to the native side, you should think about the usage pattern of these buffers. Particularly for OpenGL binding libraries, you'll frequently need a `ByteBuffer` that only has space for 16 `float` values, for example (e.g. containing a matrix that is sent to OpenGL). And in many cases, the methods that do the data transfer with these buffers will be called *frequently*.

In such a case, it is usually **not** a good idea to allocate these small, short-lived buffers repeatedly:

```
class Renderer {
    void renderMethodThatIsCalledThousandsOfTimesPerSecond() {
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16 * 4);
        fill(bb);
        passToOpenGL(bb);
    }
}
```

The creation of these buffers and the GC can significantly reduce performance - and distressingly in the form of GC pauses, that could cause lags in a game.

For such cases, it can be beneficial to pull out the allocation, and re-use the buffer:

```
class Renderer {

    private final ByteBuffer MATRIX_BUFFER_4x4 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16 * 4);

    void renderMethodThatIsCalledThousandsOfTimesPerSecond() {
        fill(MATRIX_BUFFER_4x4);
        passToOpenGL(MATRIX_BUFFER_4x4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is highly worth mentioning for performance reasons. 
Right now I'm just using assimp in Java code and fear memory leaks though.