# Is there any off-heap lock-free data structure (list, set, map etc..) on Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, lock-free

I have found several off heap in memory data storage, such as Chronicle-Map, mapdb, etc... They all have usage of locks (stamped read write lock, or reentrant read write lock).

Is there any data structure that is off heap and lock free on Java? Or is there any off heap data structure that is read-lock-free?

Comment: What do you mean by an "off-heap" data structure? I thought all objects were stored on the heap.

Comment: @NomadMaker https://stackoverflow.com/q/6091615/12323248

Comment: there is no such thing as lock-free data structure. They use locks anyway, in the form of compare-and-swap machine instruction. So if you are looking for fast data structures, just measure the speed of this and that structures. I doubt you can beat the speed of Chronicle data structures.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov I think "lock-free data structure" is a pretty established term in [non-blocking synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm). And yes, CAS is mostly (always?) used, which is a machine instruction, not a lock. What do you mean by CAS being a lock?

Comment: @akuzminykh I mean that when contention, CAS wood try and try in a loop, effectively blocking the algorithm, until contention is dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

Agrona's [ring buffer](https://github.com/real-logic/agrona/blob/master/agrona/src/main/java/org/agrona/concurrent/ringbuffer/OneToOneRingBuffer.java) is fully lock free off-heap data structure. This queue could be used as inter-process-communication library (and actually is used inside [aeron](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron)) and doesn't leverage any locks/system calls for message passing. Besides that, I'm pretty sure Agrona has more off-heap data structures, so you might want to check it out.

Comment: I don't think the OP is interested in ring buffers, and I don't think Agrona supplies off-heap lists, sets, maps.

Answer (score 0):

Lock-free is not necessarily faster than lock-based.

In modern JVMs, built-in locks are extremely fast, and beat old lock-free algorithms by a high magnitude.

This looks like an XY problem. What are you trying to achieve?